# how do i make different touch and click behaviours for buttons?

Tags: android, button, android-layout, onclick, touch-event

Im working on an app with a friend and i want the button to visually press by changing the background and vibrating and then when released it does whatever that button is supposed to do.

the buttons i have right now only have an onclick method but i want it vibrate when touched and execute their function when clicked

i know of the ontouch and onclick methods but i cant seem to use them togetherand have already implemented both onclicklistener and ontouchlistener

how might i manage this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by only using the OnTouchListener:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        /* Change your button background and vibrate */
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        /* Button's functionality */
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this works but on apps that i have found if you move somewhere else on the screen when pressing it the button wont click, with this code it does, im starting to think that it has something to do with the drawable thing i the xml file

any ideas?